# Check if the characters in a string are contained in any of the word of a list

Tags: python, string, list, indexing, substring

I need to find a way to check if given characters are contained in any of the words of a very long list.

I suppose you could do it by checking every indexes of the words in the list, a bit like so:

```
for i in list:
    if i[0] == 'a' or 'b':
       found_words.append(i)
    if i[1] == 'a' or 'b':
       found_words.append(i)
```

But this is not a very stylish and not a very efficient way of doing it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: best way to get help is to show your input, code, current output and expected output

Comment: `if i[0] == 'a' or 'b'` is probably not what you want. It translates to `i[0] == 'a'` OR `'b'` where the second part is always true. Better `i[0] in ('a', 'b')`.

Comment: Please include an example of the input, and the expected output, this will clarify what you need.

Comment: You could use [**`sets`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset): `if set(i[:2]) <= set('ab')`

Comment: `set(w for w in word_list if re.search(r'[ab]', w, re.I))`

Comment: Did you mean to just check the first two characters in the string? Or do you want to check all characters in all strings?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know my description is not very clear. Basically, I want to retrieve words from a list containing some letters, no matter their indexes. I have a huge list containing thousands of words. I want to select all the words containing some letters, for example a,b,c,d,e. I think i might have to use the re module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more understandable way of doing this is the following:

```
character='e'

for i in list:
    if character in i:
       found_words.append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
check = set('ab').intersection  # the letters to check against
lst = [...]  # the words, do not shadow the built-in 'list'

found_words = [w for w in lst if check(w)]
```

or shorter:

```
found_words = list(filter(check, lst))
```

Comment: It's possible from the question that `w` is more than 2 characters.

Comment: @PeterWood How would that affect my answer?

Comment: The letters `ab` might not be at the first and second indices.

Comment: @PeterWood Then they'd just need to change the set.

Comment: @PeterWood Can you provide a set of inputs that would fail with this code?

Comment: `['1234ab']` would fail.

Comment: @PeterWood I am fairly sure, the OP was meaning to check the other indeces of `w` as well: *" by checking every indexes of the words"*

Comment: I've asked OP for clarification.

Comment: @PeterWood Oh, I see. You're going by the interpretation from the code in the OP that they just want to see if the first two characters match? I guess they have to clarify, because the description sounds to me like they just want to see if the letters are in there anywhere.

Comment: I can see that interpretation now that I read it more slowly. I'm still not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match characters in lists, you can use regular expressions.

```py
import re

for i in lst:
    re.match(str,i) #returns "true", use in conditionals
```

Replace "str" with the characters you want to check for, e.g "[abcde]", which matches "a","b","c","d", or "e" in any word, or "[abcde][pqrst]" which matches any combination of "ap", "at", "eq", etc. Do so with a variable so you can change it far more easily.